# Getting problem while setting the position attribute of the Buffer Geometry

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am setting the position of position attributes of the buffer geometry using the `Math.sin()` and `Math.cos()` and I am getting this error

> THREE.BufferGeometry.computeBoundingSphere(): Computed radius is NaN.
> The "position" attribute is likely to have NaN values.

[image: image of the code]

I am expecting no error and the simply can fill this value inside it

Comment: Please read [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're using `Math.PI.branches`, which doesn't exist, so `branchAngle` is NaN (Not a Number). From there on out, everything that uses `branchAngle` is gonna be NaN, and your BufferGeometry will be invalid.

Also, instead of posting screenshots of code, please paste the code itself in text form.